# Password reset in Django

Tags: python, django

I did a password reset on the site, but I could not find on the Internet how to change this data to my own.

[image: screenshot of password reset page]

Comment: What do you mean with "this data"? Like [changing a password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.